# Node Cluster in Production Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

When using cluster in production, specifically calling the fork() function, I get this error, both locally and on Heroku. I have set a variable for WEB_CONCURRENCY = 1. When I remove cluster from my server.js it works fine.

//server.js

```
let WORKERS = process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || 1;
let cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < WORKERS; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.id} exit`);
    cluster.fork();
  });
}
else { ... setup Express }
```

//

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/server/undefined'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
worker 150 exit // (failed again)
module.js:549
throw err;
```

However, when I run this locally, not in production, `node server.js` it works fine, I could make multiple clusters and no error. What does this error mean, and why does it fail on Heroku/production? Thanks.